# Control USB power by USB power

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to power a Raspi from a Power Supply but I would like to switch it on and off depending on if the USB out from the TV is on or off (the USB from TV is not needed for anything except signaling if TV is on or off).

Prinicpally the TV could power the Raspi but that's just beyond the normal USB power specs, so I'd like a safer solution but keep the on/off logic tied to the TV as the Raspi is useful only with TV on.

Is there something like that out there? How could it be done? TIA!

Comment: Use a solid state relay activating the AC power to the power supply.

Comment: Have you checked if the TV turns off power to USB when it is in stand-by?

Comment: Yes, that is the case, USB power turns off

Comment: The biggest thing to think about here is that you should not be turning off a pi's power without first shutting down the operating system!  It probably makes more sense to build a system where the pi can shut itself down, after being started up by the turn-on of the TV.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 5V relay module [like this one](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07QKXQ6VM/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_dYVdEbSB3143R). Your design will have the following connections:

[image: 5V relay module]

1. DC+ to USB 5V
2. DC- to USB 0V
3. IN1 to USB 5V
4. NO to your raspberry pi 5V in
5. COM to the 5V raspberry pi wall wort/plug socket power supply
6. NC disconnected

N.b The wall wort power supply's ground also needs connected to the raspberry pi. This can be connected directly (not through the relay) and does not have to be connected to the relay DC-

Comment: You should consider copying the detailed product description as a picture into your answer so that it's clear what DC+ and DC- mean. HyperLinks are easily broken and your answer basically will "fail" with a loss of link.

Comment: Please at least mention it's a module - my first thought was that powering a coil from USB's D+ at best won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using a relay as Michael Jennings suggests is a good solution.

---

If you want the easiest possible solution then a premade relay module which are available on Amazon
[ [Many examples here](https://www.amazon.com/5v-relay-module/s?k=5v+relay+module) ] and various Asian sites would be a good choice.

---

A more DIY electronic solution is to use a transistor as a switch. 
I've shown a MOSFET here but an NPN transistor could be used with suitable component changes.

This depends on the Pi power supply output being isolated from its input, which will be the case in all but a very few special cases.

The low current supply provides a positive level via R1 to the MOSFET gate to turn it on, thereby powering the load. M! can be any N Channel MOSFET with Rdson (on resistance) below about 0.1 Ohm, 20V or better Vds  and and Ids (current rating) of say 5A or more. This is a very modest specification nowadays.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftAEam.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Switching the ground side of the Pi sounds like a recipe for trouble, if it's connected back to the TV. I bet the Pi's ground is connected to the TV's ground via the HDMI cable.

Comment: Sounds interesting especially as there does not seem to exist any ready solution (i.e. module with USB connectors) for this problem at all....

Comment: @StefanHegny  The relay solution (see links to amazon examples) is the easiest one and will work well. With a DPDT relay or 2 x SPDT relays you can switch both power leads if desired - but V+ alone should do. (Actually you need only xPST relays but the cheap modules always come as double throw (ie changeover). ||SPDT = single contact changeover. DPDT = double contact changeover

Comment: @user253751 Good point. Could be. A relay module is by far the easiest option. See my prior comment here. | The high current supply = psu is floating (almost certainly) so no problem. TV USB ground will quite possibly muck things up.